# How do I reference a master page from an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

How do I reference a master page from an ASP.NET webform?  The following statement does not work:

```
this.MasterPage.Page.Title = "My Title";
```

Answer (score 8):

In your aspx, below the Page directive, write:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="YourMasterFile" %>
```

And then from your code, write Master. anything that you want to use, for example:

```
Master.Title = "My Title";
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to cast this.MasterPage into the type of masterpage you have, and then you can access it as you'd expect

```
var mp = this.MasterPage as MyMasterPageType;
mp.Property = value... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Page you can use the `Master` property and cast this to your master page.  i.e. `(MyMasterPage)this.Master`.  However, whenever I attempt to do this I always check it can be cast first so I normally end up with something like...

```
MyMasterPage master;
if (this.Master is MyMasterPage)
{
    master = (MyMasterPage)this.Master
    //do stuff with master.
}
```

If all you are wanting to do is change the title then you can just use `Page.Title` and make sure that the head tag in your master page is set to runat='server'.

Answer (score 0):

In your code write :

```
Dim masterpage As New MasterPage
    masterpage = CType(masterpage, MasterPage)
```

and in your source code where the language is defined and etc type this

```
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
```

If you write in C#

```
 MasterPage masterpage = new MasterPage();
masterpage = (MasterPage)masterpage;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial question (before it was edited) I think you mentioned "global settings". Depending on what you want to do, you may want to look into the BasePage concept as well, since I think it might be more suitable. Since you derive from it, all its members are accessible in your code-behind.