# How to turn on the visibility of a <a> which is on the master page from code behind file?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Here is the snippet of the code inside my master page.

```
<section id="login">
    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a id="logoutLink" runat="server" href="#" visible="false">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</section>
```

I would like to turn on the visibility of hyperlink with the id of `#logoutlink` from one of my pages' code behind file. I tried this way but didn't work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink x = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("logoutLink");
    x.Visible = true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [`MasterType` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917653/how-do-i-reference-a-master-page-from-an-aspx-page?rq=1). In addition, `FindControl` is _not_ recursive so you probably have to iterate recursively by yourself.

Comment: Why not do it the other way around and provide a public property `public bool LogoutLinkVisible { get { return logoutLink.Visible; } set { logoutLink.Visible = value; } }` in your master page?

Comment: It didn't work for me but anyway thank you for posting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add an ID for LoginView:

```
asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ID="loginView"
```

And then the below code will work:

```
var loginView = Master.FindControl("loginView");
var ul = loginView.Controls[0];
var loginLink = ul.FindControl("logoutLink");
```